# Why laravel eloquent multiple delete with ajax query not working properly?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vuejs3

I am trying to delete multiple rows from database.
Everything works fine except last row passed in id array is not deleted.

I am doing it with ajax and below is the link sent

```
http://local.domain.com/app/deletemultiple/[88,87]
```

And here is the code in my api controller

```
    /**
     * Remove the specified resources from storage.
     *
     * @param  $ids
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function deletemultiple($ids) {
        $idarray = json_decode($ids, TRUE);
        try {
            //$members = Member::whereIn('id', $idarray)->get();
            //return response()->json(array('success' => $members));
            $ids = explode(",", $ids);
            Member::whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
            return response()->json(array('success' => $ids));
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(array('error' => $e->getMessage()), 400);
        }
    }


//Route is as follows
Route::delete('/app/deletemultiple/{ids}', [MemberController::class, 'deletemultiple'])->name('member.deletemultiple');
```

No matter how much rows selected and passed. All rows are deleted except the last one in array. If i pass single id as array that is also not deleted.

If I uncomment this code

```
//$members = Member::whereIn('id', $idarray)->get();
//return response()->json(array('success' => $members));
```

I get proper response of all ids passed.

Expecting to delete all rows selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller you're decoding json from ids to $idarray but using $ids that's exploding your json ($ids) string to `[1` and `2]` you should pass in $idarray to whereIn for delete as this function expects array of ids (in your case).

Use this in your controller:

```
public function deletemultiple($ids) {
    $idarray = json_decode($ids, TRUE);
    try {
        Member::whereIn('id', $idarray)->delete();
        return response()->json(array('success' => $idarray));
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(array('error' => $e->getMessage()), 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. Actually i had tried with $idarray also. In backend it was deleting but my frontend was throwing error as i was returning the success response with $idarray which was handled incorrectly. Needed to send back the same $ids which was string  and it worked correctly as i was using JSON.parse in frontend.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use post method then passed a json array of ids to be deleted. Instead of passing multiple ids in the url path parameter.